# dataframe into dictionary of dataframes based on one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
df=
         column1  v1   v2 ... vN
ind1     'a'      1    3
ind1     'b'      2    4
ind2     'a'      3    5
ind2     'b'      4    6
...
indN     'c'      5    7
```

I would like to split this dataframe into a dictionary of dataframes, one for each of the original `v1..vN` columns, and to have the possible values in columns1 as new columns

ex.

```
output['v1']=
      'a'    'b'     'c'
ind1   1      2      nan
ind2   3      4       nan
indN   nan   nan       5
output['v2']=
      'a'    'b'     'c'
ind1   3      4      nan
ind2   5      6       nan
indN   nan   nan       7
```

and fill with `nans` any gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('column1', append=True).unstack()
print (df1)
          v1             v2          
column1  'a'  'b'  'c'  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  7.0
```

Then in dict comprehension select by first level of `MultiIndex` by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
output = {x:df1.xs(x, axis=1) for x in df1.columns.levels[0]}
print (output)
{'v2': column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     3.0  4.0  NaN
ind2     5.0  6.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  7.0, 'v1': column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0}

print (output['v1'])
column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0
```

But also is possible generate output from `df1` by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) without comprehension:

```
print (df1.xs('v1', axis=1))
column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0
```

---

Similar solution:

```
df1 = df.set_index('column1', append=True)
print (df1)
              v1  v2
     column1        
ind1 'a'       1   3
     'b'       2   4
ind2 'a'       3   5
     'b'       4   6
indN 'c'       5   7

output = {x:df1.unstack().xs(x, axis=1) for x in df1.columns}
print (output)
{'v2': column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     3.0  4.0  NaN
ind2     5.0  6.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  7.0, 'v1': column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0}

print (output['v1'])
column1  'a'  'b'  'c'
ind1     1.0  2.0  NaN
ind2     3.0  4.0  NaN
indN     NaN  NaN  5.0
```